# What is the use of -browser switch in the context of Grid2 for webdriver node

Tags: selenium, webdriver

What is the exact use of -browser switch while creating a webdriver node for Grid2.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=iexplore,platform=WINDOWS -port 5556
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide multiple browser versions using the switch -browser. For example if your remote system has multiple versions of firefox that you want to use then you could specify them like this,

```
-browser browserName=firefox,version=3.6,firefox_binary=/home/myhomedir/firefox36/firefox,maxInstances=3,platform=LINUX -browser browserName=firefox,version=4,firefox_binary=/home/myhomedir/firefox4/firefox,maxInstances=4,platform=LINUX
```

Check out the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)